# Get one of the Object from other class as Array

Tags: java

So I need a class `HighscoreEntry` only to hold a player name and their score. In another class `HighscoreTable` I have to make a list of the players' names and scores and also sort the scores from the highest to the lowest. How do I get only the int score to sort it out?

```
public class HighscoreEntry {

    private String name;
    private int score;

    public HighscoreEntry(String name, int score){
        this.name=name;
        this.score=score;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return this.score;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Player: "+this.name+", score: "+this.score;
    }

}
```

So theres my "entry code":

```
public class HighscoreTable {

    private HighscoreEntry [] player;

    public HighscoreTable(HighscoreEntry [] p){
        player = new HighscoreEntry[p.length];
        for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
            player[i]=p[i];
            if (player.getScore()[i]>player.getScore()[i+1]){
                // i wanted here to sort out the score only  but it doesn't work with getScore()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `player` is an `array`, i guess you want to acces the array element as `player[i].get....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the array wrongly. You can not call a non-array method on an array.

```
if (player.getScore()[i]>player.getScore()[i+1])
```

The variable `player` is an Array and thus you can not call `getScore` on it. You have to access the object first with `player[i]` and then call the method like this

```
player[i].getScore();
```

Comment: @AJPermadi Okay, you might aswell accept the answer.

Comment: i did, i have another problem though, so i did this `public HighscoreTable(HighscoreEntry [] p){
  player = new HighscoreEntry[p.length];
  
  for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
   player[i]=p[i];
   
   
   if(player[i].getScore()<player[i+1].getScore()){
    
    int tmp = 0;
    
    tmp=player[i].getScore();
    player[i].getScore()=player[i+1].getScore();
    player[i+1].getScore()=tmp;
    
   }
   
  }` but it says on the last 2 rows: the left-hand side must be variable. i know what it means, but i thought player[i].getScore is already a variable no ?

Comment: @AJPermadi That's a different question. In short - no that's not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an array index like that.

```
player.getScore()[i]>player.getScore()[i+1]
```

needs to become

```
player[i].getScore() > player[i+1].getScore()
```

I also wouldn't Go about accessing an index like that without having any condition to check if you are at the last index.

```
player[i+1].getScore()
```

Can result in an out of bounds exception.

Comment: oh yeah! i'll just compare it till i-2 then :D thankyouuuu!

Answer (score 0):

As Murat K. states in his answer, you access the array in a wrong way. But your sorting algorithm would not work anyway. While implementing an algorithm to sort arrays is fairly easy, I would recommend to use the 'default' way to do it in Java, utilizing the Collection Framework:

Instead of saving your `HighscoreEntry`s in an array, store them in a list, e.g. an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Then let `HighscoreEntry` implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The code for `HighscoreEntry` would then look like:

```
public class HighscoreEntry implements Comparable<HighscoreEntry> {

    private int score;

    public int compareTo(HighscoreEntry he) {
        return score - he.score;
    }

    [other code]

}
```

You are then able to sort your entries like:

```
List<HighscoreEntry> list = Arrays.asList(player);
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: thank you very much! but we're not that far though, we're still in chapter top and inherited class, so we have to write it from scratch :b